# При увеличение масштаба страницы в браузере, ломается структура верхнего меню

Tags: bootstrap, меню

Сайт:     https://gooentry.000webhostapp.com/bs.html
[image: Вид при 100%]
[image: Вид при увеличение масштаба]
 Подскажите в каком направлении работать?
   введите сюда код See the Pen [Top_menu Bootstrap4](https://codepen.io/vvv7220/pen/pqZYLa/) by Vladimir ([@vvv7220](https://codepen.io/vvv7220)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

`введите сюда код`

Answer (score 0):

Я увидел, что вы используете bootstrap.

Рекомендую использовать стандартные компоненты bootstrap и оформлять их как захочется. Тогда об адаптивности можно будет не думать bootstrap всё сделает за вас и на любом устройстве получите правильное отображение!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
   target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria- 
   expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only"> 
        (current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

http://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.2.1/components/navbar/

Comment: На бутсрапе тоже сделал вариант. Чуть получше. Но тоже один пункт меню складывается.
https://gooentry.000webhostapp.com/bs_02.html

Comment: Не увидел какой именно, вроде всё складывается. 
Ещё рекомендую использовать flex для правильного выравнивания. А то получается что номер телефона и соц. кнопки выступают пунктами меню.
http://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.2.1/utilities/flex/

Comment: Не поняли меня. При увеличение масштаба 4-й пункт меню переносится на другую строку. Плохо что в комментах нельзя скрины прикреплять. Флекс я применил, но возможно не правильно